# problems with Lua match to find a pattern

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I'm struggling with this problem:

Given 2 strings:

```
s1 = '/foo/:bar/oof/:rab'
s2 = '/foo/lua/oof/rocks'
```

I would like to produce the following information:

1. If they match (these two above should match, s2 follows a pattern described in s1).
2. A table holding the values of `s2` in with the corresponding name in `s1`. In this case we would have: `{ bar = "lua", rab = "rocks" }`

I think this algorithm solves it, but I can't figure how to implement it (probably with gmatch):

1. store the placeholders `:` indexes as KEYS of a table, and the respective VALUES being the name of these placeholders.

   Example with `s1`:

   ```
   local aux1 = { "6" = "bar", "15" = "rab" }
   ```
2. With the keys of `aux1` fetched as indexes, extract the values of `s2`
   into another table:

   ```
   local aux2 = {"6" = "lua", "15" = "rocks"}
   ```
3. Finally merge them two into one table (this one is easy :P)

   ```
   { bar = "lua", rab = "rocks" }
   ```

Comment: In step 2 you are using the indices from s1 to lookup spots in s2, this only works since ":bar" is the same length as "lua", will this always be the case?

Comment: actually there is a flaw in this logic, i am working on a solution based on spliting the strings on "/"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
function comp(a,b)
  local t = {}
  local i, len_a = 0
  for w in (a..'/'):gmatch('(.-)/') do
    i = i + 1
    if w:sub(1,1) == ':' then
      t[ -i ] = w:sub(2)
    else
      t[ i ] = w
    end
  end
  len_a = i
  i = 0
  local ans = {}
  for w in (b..'/'):gmatch('(.-)/') do
    i = i + 1
    if t[ i ] and t[ i ] ~= w then
      return {}
    elseif t[ -i ] then
      ans[ t[ -i ] ] = w
    end
  end
  if len_a ~= i then return {} end
  return ans
end

s1 = '/foo/:bar/oof/:rab'
s2 = '/foo/lua/oof/rocks'

for k,v in pairs(comp(s1,s2)) do print(k,v) end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be:

```
s1 = '/foo/:bar/oof/:rab'
s2 = '/foo/lua/oof/rocks'
pattern = "/([^/]+)"

function getStrngTable(_strng,_pattern)
    local t = {}
    for val in string.gmatch(_strng,_pattern) do
        table.insert(t,val)
    end
    return t
end
local r = {}
t1 = getStrngTable(s1,pattern)
t2 = getStrngTable(s2,pattern)
for k = 1,#t1 do
    if (t1[k] == t2[k]) then
        r[t1[k + 1]:match(":(.+)")] = t2[k + 1]
    end
end
```

The Table `r` will have the required result

The solution below, which is some what cleaner, will also give the same result:

```
 s1 = '/foo/:bar/oof/:rab'
 s2 = '/foo/lua/oof/rocks'
 pattern = "/:?([^/]+)"

 function getStrng(_strng,_pattern)
     local t = {}
     for val in string.gmatch(_strng,_pattern) do
         table.insert(t,val)     
     end
     return t
 end
 local r = {}
 t1 = getStrng(s1,pattern)
 t2 = getStrng(s2,pattern)


 for k = 1,#t1 do
     if (t1[k] == t2[k]) then
         r[t1[k + 1]] = t2[k + 1]
     end
 end
```